# django class based view multiple form validatiton

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm currently trying to have **two** forms on a single page. I'm using Class Based Views.

```
class TaskDetailView(FormMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Task
    template_name="tasks/detail.html"
    form_class = NoteForm
    form_class2 = DurationForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TaskDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['note_form'] = self.get_form()
        context['notes'] = Note.objects.filter(task__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        context['duration_form'] = self.form_class2()
        context['duration'] = Duration.objects.all()
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse('task_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.kwargs['slug']})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated: 
            return HttpResponseForbidden
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        current_task = get_object_or_404(Task, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.task =  current_task
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponse(self.get_success_url())
```

My current status is that I'm able to display all the forms and save ONLY the Notes form. I'm not able to save the Duration Form despite there's a 200 status POST, the data is not being saved to the database.

I think my mistake is that I'm not validating it but I'm really not sure how to, and there isn't much information on multiple forms on CBVs in Django.

I would really appreciate some guidance and assistance.

Thanks

Comment: Re-think your design as your path leads to confusion. First of all, a browser will only send *ONE* of the two forms. HTML doesn't allow nesting and tweaking your template to show two forms as one form with two submit buttons is error prone and working against the design of Django's form class. This means you need a way at runtime to select the form to use and for that there is a perfect method [get_form_class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_class). But by far the easiest is to use 2 different URLS.

Comment: Hi Melvyn, so is this just django-specific issue that multiple forms on a single page is not really suitable?

Comment: Hi max. Yes and no. A browser only sends one form at a time. From this standpoint it makes little sense to design a page or view object to handle multiple forms. Especially since it's very easy to handle the two forms on two different URLs. If you have a ModelForm for Apples that handles a foreign key to another ModelForm Basket, then you should use formsets and only register the Basket form with the view. But from your question I understand these two forms aren't related, but accomplish two different tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `post` method doesn't do anything with the second form. You'd need to instantiate it and check its validity as you do with the first one.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how I can do that. Do you have any url that I can read from? My current codes are all from different tuts put together.

Comment: Not sure what URL you want. You instantiate the first form and check it is valid, now you need to do the same with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

A quite simple way of having multiple forms on one page would be to define some hidden parameter to differentiate between your POST actions, like:

```
<input name="formType" type="hidden" value="note">
```

In your CBV post method, you could:

```
form_type = request.POST.get('formType', None)
if form_type == 'note':
```